# Huge List<double> save in small file

Tags: c#

I am trying to save a huge list of doubles in a file. For now it looks like this:

```
try{
       FileStream fs = new FileStream(saveFileDialog.FileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);                   
       using(BinaryWriter binaryWriter = new BinaryWriter(fs))
       {
             foreach (double value in bigData)
             {
                  binaryWriter.Write(value);
             }
             binaryWriter.Close();
        }
        fs.Close();
} catch(System.IO.FileNotFoundException)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Unexpected save error\n", "Save error!", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
}
```

`bigData is a List<double>` and in test case it contains 2 millions objects.

The saved file has around *15MB*, which I think is quite a lot for only binary data. Has anyone got any idea, how I can make it much smaller?

Also, remember, that I need to open this file after saving - but this is done in another method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The saved file has around 15MB, which I think is quite a lot for only binary data.

Well, a [`double`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is 8 bytes of data:

> The `Double` value type represents a double-precision 64-bit number

You've got 2 million of them, so that means 16 million bytes. Seems about right to me.

Perhaps you actually want `float` values instead? That would save half the size... at the cost of precision and range, of course.

Compressing the data *may* help, but it may not - it depends on whether or not it contains a lot of repetitive information. You may find that compressing it *increases* the size rather than decreasing it - that's just the nature of having that many *possible* values.

Without knowing more about your context, we can't tell whether you really have 15MB of *useful information* or whether there's natural redundancy.

Comment: It is useful data. You are right with calculations. I've made mistake in mine and this is why I wanted it to be compressed.

Comment: @sebap123: I'm not saying that the data points aren't useful, but do you actually need them to be 64 bits of information per value? Don't assume that compression will help - depending on the kind of data you're using, it may well not.

Comment: @JimMischel: My mistake - was thinking of BinaryFormatter. Will remove that

Answer (score 9):

A double is [8 bytes long](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), so 2 million times 8 is about 16MB. Seems OK.

Answer (score 2):

[Compress it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.gzipstream%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)! Note, as [John states](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20685130/80274), depending on the data you may get really really good compression and your file may only be a few 100 K in size (you entered the same `double` 2 million times) or you may get up a file that is ***larger*** than the uncompressed version (the values of the doubles are the output of a good random number generator that generates 8 bytes at a time). Both extremes are highly unlikely and you will likely get some form of middle ground that will shave off a few MB, but you should be aware of the possibilities.

```
try
{
    using(FileStream fs = new FileStream(saveFileDialog.FileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
    using(GZipStream gz = new GZipStream(fs, CompressionMode.Compress))
    using(BinaryWriter binaryWriter = new BinaryWriter(gz))
    {
        foreach (double value in bigData)
        {
          binaryWriter.Write(value);
        }
    }
} catch(System.IO.FileNotFoundException)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Unexpected save error\n",
    "Save error!", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
}
```

When you go to read it you just set the mode to Decompress instead

```
    using(FileStream fs = new FileStream(openFileDialog.FileName, FileMode.Open))
    using(GZipStream gz = new GZipStream(fs, CompressionMode.Decompress))
    using(BinaryReader binaryReader = new BinaryReader(gz))
    {
        //(use the reader as normal here)
    }
```

Also you should have put `fs` in a `using` statement and if you are using `using` statements you don't need to call `.Close()`.

Answer (score 1):

Compress the file using Zip algorithm, there are plenty of free implementations around. One of them (conveniently as a NuGet package): [DotNetZip](http://www.nuget.org/packages/DotNetZip/)

Same library can be used for opening the file.